# Get value from resource using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Hello I am trying to get the value from a Key in the a resource file using reflection. However it I am struggling. I build the namespace and the culture but the value always comes out null.

```
    public static string GetResource(string language)
    {
        var culture = (language == "en-US") ? string.Empty : $".{language}";

        var resource = Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Test"))
            .Single(x => x.Namespace == $"ConsoleApp1.Resources{culture}");
        resource.GetProperty("Hello");//this is always null

        return null;
    }
```

I am not sure why this is but I know that i am getting the correct resource and I see the property in it. does anyone have any sugestions?

Hello property:

```
    internal static string Hello {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("Hello", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share the code for Hello property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 'Hello' property is `internal` and `static`, we should specify it:

```
resource.GetProperty("Hello", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
```